# how to verify that a select box has an element?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am stuck trying to verify that a drop down box has the required item?

For example following is the drop down box in question

```
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I am using Selenium IDE. I am wondering what the following params should be

```
Command:
Target:
Value:
```

if i am intending to check if "Audi" is one of the items in the drop down box?

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `verifyText` command in selenium IDE to make your your intended element is present or not with given text

Here you go -

```
Command: verifyText
Target: css=option[value="Audi"]
Value: Audi
```

Comment: i dont think this is a general solution. I am looking for a general solution i.e to verify whether an item is present in the select element. The item can be located in any index.

Comment: That solution WILL work regardless of the index. Though maybe you want VerifyElementPresent instead of verify Text?